# How to do a best fit vertical align

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dialog

I'm seeing a lot of "how to vertically align stuff" type questions but I can't seem to find anything that solves this particular problem.

I have 3 "sections" in a jquery dialog and I want them to sit vertically in the space without leaving big gaps in between them.
I don't know their heights as their content is dynamic and changes.

Here's a fiddle showing what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTQS8/

In it's simplest form the code looks something like this (just imagine that all the br tags are real content though)

```
<div class="jqDialog">
   <section>
       <br/><br/>
   </section>
   <section>
       <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
   </section>
   <section>
       <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
   </section>
</div>
```

Then my current css:

```
section { 
    border: solid 1px #DADADA; 
    margin: 5px; 
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px; 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I want the bottom section to automatically fill the space above it if possible.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Maybe I wasn't clear enough ...

This is my ideal result:
http://jsfiddle.net/PTQS8/2/

However bear in mind that the content in the sections is all dynamic so the style definition for "section3" would need to have a dynamic negative top margin in order for this to work.

Figuring this out could be possible with javascript I suppose but I was hoping there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you add an image of what you expect to happen? I don't have it clear yet. Do you wan them vertically centered in the page?

Comment: all im trying to do is find an elegant way to "ditch the gap" between sections 1 and 3 on the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PTQS8/3/

```
<div class="jqDialog">
   <section>
       <br/><br/>
   </section>
   <section class="section2">
       <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
   </section>
   <section class="section3">
       <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
   </section>
</div>
```

and the css ...

```
section { 
    border: solid 1px #DADADA; 
    margin: 5px; 
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px; 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.section2 { float: right; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--The simplest way is to use the span and float properties.-->
<!--Make use of table if you dont like the gap between the left and right panes-->
    <div class="jqDialog">
       <span style="float: left"><section>
           <br/><br/>
           </section></span>
       <span style="float: right"><section>
           <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
           </section></span><span  style="float: left">
       <section>
           <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </section></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: spans should not be used in this way (non standard) using a table layout would produce the problem I'm trying to resolve. However floating section 2 may help ...

Comment: interesting ... http://jsfiddle.net/PTQS8/3/ does seem to solve my problem ... i just need to clean this up a bit ... cheers :)

Comment: my edit of this post is the final solution (assuming you don't mind the edit) ... i did consider posting this as an answer myself but you are practically there :)

Comment: I agree that is non-standard, but happy that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them vertically centered, change `width:200px` to `width:100%;`